# Save text file that auto increments file_01.txt, file_02.txt, file_03.txt C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am making a program using winforms, and when I save my text file I want it to auto increment.
Example saves as file_01.txt, file_02.txt, file_03.txt

I can't seem to get it to work...

Here's my code

```
        private void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
        { 
            string filePath = "C\\";
            int fileCount = 0;
            String fileName = "File_0" + $"{fileCount}";
            bool checkFileName = true;
            while (checkFileName)
            {
                fileName = "File_0" + $"{fileCount}.txt";
                fileCount++;

                string checkName = filePath + "\\" + fileName;
                checkFileName = File.Exists(checkName);
            }

            saveFileDialog.FileName = fileName;
            saveFileDialog.Title = "Save Files";
            saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $"{filePath}";
            saveFileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "txt";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files |*.txt";
            saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.OpenFile()))
                {
                    foreach (string item in regoListBox.Items)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are having? Do you want each item in `regoListBox.Items` to have a seperate text file?

Comment: No error, I want the .txt file to increment every time I save

Comment: Your code works. Can you share what error output do you get from calling the `saveFile()` function?

Comment: No error, it saves. but only see one text file each time I save, only shows File_00.txt, next time i save it should save as File_01.txt, then File_002.txt and so on..

Comment: Yes your the `filePath` is incorrect, you forgot to add colon in the path, should be like this `C:\\`. I have added it as answer. If it solves your issue, please do accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because you are not specifying `filePath` correctly. Therefore it fails to check for incremental filenames.

Change it to this:

```cs
//string filePath = "C\\";
string filePath = "C:\\";
```